# "Table 'nova.services' does not exist" error in Openstack

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I am a newbie to Openstack. I am using Openstack Diablo with 3 machines, 2 servers and one client. In server one, everything is installed and running fine. In server two, when I run the command `sudo nova-manage service list`, it gives the following error:

```
TRACE nova ProgrammingError:  (ProgrammingError) (1146, "Table 'nova.services' does not exist")
```

I tried `nova-manage db sync` in server one. Still same error. Any solutions?

Update : I found what's wrong. I was using the nova-manage db sync in server one. I tried it on server 2 and the issue was solved.

Comment: OpenStack *Diablo* is relatively ancient ([end-of-life in 2011](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Releases)).  Have you considered running something more recent?

Comment: @larsks Yes, but the newer versions need more machines and currently I have only 3.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem.  Newer versions do not require more machines.  You can run Kilo on a single machine if you want, or 1 controller + 2 computes, or whatever.  You are missing out on features and bugfixes that will make your life easier.

Comment: @larsks Thanks for the suggestion. I will try the new version.

Answer (score 1):

I found what's wrong. I was using `the nova-manage db sync` in server one. I tried it on server 2 and the issue was solved.

Comment: I think this is not an answer and you should consider adding it as an 'edit' or 'update' to your original question.

Comment: @Athafoud Answering your own questions is ok and even encouraged. This is a valid answer.

Comment: @runDOSrun Yes, I agree. But I think that the particular answer is not very constructive. Maybe it has to do with the fact that the initial question, is about a 'user mistake'.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `nova-manage cell_v2 simple_cell_setup`